# Create custom TER (TYPO3) server

Tags: typo3

Recently I saw that the Extension Manager knows where the TER is located from the table `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository` which in all installations I know only contains 1 record. That one record has (amongst others) these values in its columns:

```
uid = 1
pid = 0
title = "TYPO3.org Main Repository"
wsdl_url = "https://typo3.org/wsdl/tx_ter_wsdl.php"
mirror_list_url = "https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz"
```

There are 3 questions now:

1. Is there any documentation/reference on how a TER server has to work/respond?
2. Can I create my own custom TER server so that the extension manager can install and upgrade extensions from there?
3. What happens if I add a new record to that mentioned table? Will it work as a secondary TER so that the Extension Manager merges its results with those from the official TER? Or will it just view it as a mirror and only access it if the official TER is offline?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in self-hosting packages and distributing them, or in managing a specific selection of packages, withholding some updates, deploying your own packages, or anything similar: Try looking into composer: https://composer.typo3.org

It is a package and dependency manager tool which allows a big amount of freedom and hackability and basically replaces TER if you decide to install TYPO3 that way.

At least all projects that looked into "custom TER" I know were disregarded later in honour of composer.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Well, the installations I'm talking about can not be set up using composer sadly because of hosting restrictions. Also I want admin users to be able to install and upgrade the provided extensions without using SSH or any other command line.

Comment: Maybe it's about time to generally think about your development and deployment strategy. Some points to think about:

Composer will definitely the way to go in the future.
With a proper deployment process, you don't need composer on the hosting machine.
Do you really want any admin to install extensions (maybe even on the production website).
Most of the extensions need some kind of configuration  which should be file based and not in the database.

From own experience I know that it's a hard process, but it pays of for sure!